# Match this name and mac address if it is not associated with this ip using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the name and mac address that is NOT associated with the ip 172.16.1.102 using regex in the test string example below.

In this case the output I would like is (eth1, 00:e0:4c:68:ce:52).
As 'inet 172.16.1.102' is associated with eth0 and the address d8:bb:c1:57:42:82.

The name will be standard ubuntu ethernet adapters, so not necessarily eth1 as in this case.

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 172.16.1.102 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 172.16.1.255
inet6 fe80::dabb:c1ff:fe57:4282 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether d8:bb:c1:57:42:82 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 1103615 bytes 1565295587 (1.5 GB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 1030880 bytes 799141588 (799.1 MB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0


eth1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 00:e0:4c:68:ce:52 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0


lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
RX packets 1777991522 bytes 108254434164 (108.2 GB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 1777991522 bytes 108254434164 (108.2 GB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0


wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether b8:08:cf:a0:7c:2e txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

As an example:
The python regex I have previously used to match the name and mac address that IS associated with the ip 172.16.1.102:

```
.*((?<!\w)e\w+): flags.*(inet 172.16.1.102).*?(\w{2}[:]\w{2}[:]\w{2}[:]\w{2}[:]\w{2}[:]\w{2})
```

So perhaps if there is a way to say not 'inet 172.16.1.102' in the above expression?

Example 2:
This regex should also work in this case:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether d8:bb:c1:57:42:82 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 1103615 bytes 1565295587 (1.5 GB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 1030880 bytes 799141588 (799.1 MB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0


eth1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 172.16.1.102 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 172.16.1.255
inet6 fe80::dabb:c1ff:fe57:4282 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 00:e0:4c:68:ce:52 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0


lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
RX packets 1777991522 bytes 108254434164 (108.2 GB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 1777991522 bytes 108254434164 (108.2 GB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0


wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether b8:08:cf:a0:7c:2e txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

And the output for this should be (eth0, d8:bb:c1:57:42:82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it with regex is by checking that your ip is not found between the name and the address:

```
^(eth\d+)((?!.*172.16.1.102)[^\n]+\n)*ether ([\w:]+)((?!.*172.16.1.102)[^\n]+\n)*$
```

Explanation:

- `(eth\d+)`: eth word with more than one digit
- `((?!.*172.16.1.102)[^\n]+\n)*`: anything between the name and the address

  - `(?!.*172.16.1.102)`: negative lookahead that won't match if finds the hot ip
  - `[^\n]+`: anything different than new line
  - `\n`: new line
- `ether` : ether followed by space
- `([\w:]+)`: the address as combination of alphanumeric characters and colons
- `((?!.*172.16.1.102)[^\n]+\n)*`: anything after the address
- `$`: end of string

Your infos will be in:

- Group 1 >> name
- Group 3 >> address

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/kCjjkp/2).

Comment: Thanks, this works in this case. But if I adjust the example to lines 2 and 3 to be deleted, and instead put them below the eth1 line. Then eth0 and d8:bb:c1:57:42:82 should be matched. I'm not sure the above regex using negative lookahead would work for this also

Comment: Can you update the question with a full case of this example? @emily-s

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your new requirements correctly, though if my current update does not solve your problem, ping me here.